# Checkbox selection issue with multiple selection

Tags: java, android

I have 8 check boxes that refer to weekdays, Sunday to Saturday, and one for all days. The problem is that if I select all days it is coming. But I check all and uncheck some days means it is not reflecting in my result , the result remains all days here is my code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnSave) {
            days.clear();
            if (all.isChecked()) {

                days.add("Su");
                days.add("Mo");
                days.add("Tu");
                days.add("We");
                days.add("Th");
                days.add("Fr");
                days.add("Sa");
            } else {
                if (sun.isChecked()) {
                    days.add("Sun");
                }
                if (mon.isChecked()) {
                    days.add("Mon");
                }
                if (tue.isChecked()) {
                    days.add("Tue");
                }
                if (wed.isChecked()) {
                    days.add("Wed");
                }
                if (thur.isChecked()) {
                    days.add("Thu");
                }
                if (fri.isChecked()) {
                    days.add("Fri");
                }
                if (sat.isChecked()) {
                    days.add("Sat");
                }
            }

            Log.d("my days are ", "size is " + days.size());
            myPreference.setNumberOfPractiseDays("TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_DAYS",
                    days.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++) {
                myPreference.setPractiseDays("DAYS" + i, days.get(i));
            }
            finish();

        } else if (v == all) {
            if (all.isChecked()) {
                sun.setChecked(true);
                mon.setChecked(true);
                tue.setChecked(true);
                wed.setChecked(true);
                thur.setChecked(true);
                fri.setChecked(true);
                sat.setChecked(true);

            } else {
                sun.setChecked(false);
                mon.setChecked(false);
                tue.setChecked(false);
                wed.setChecked(false);
                thur.setChecked(false);
                fri.setChecked(false);
                sat.setChecked(false);
            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not getting isChecked() result or UI is not changing?

Comment: because you are not unchecking the `all` if any of the checkboxes are unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

If your user is checking All Days then uncheck "Thursday" for example you can handle that with a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++){
   if(!days.get(i).isChecked){
      all.uncheck();
   }
}
```

Cheers !

Comment: if(!dayNums.get(i).isChecked) is working i can find only isempty....ischecked i cant find

Answer (score 0):

```
if (v == btnSave) {
    days.clear();

   //modify starts

   for(int i = 0; i < dayNums.size(); i++){
      if(!dayNums.get(i).isChecked()){  // here dayNums is an array with values like ("sun", "mon")
         all.setChecked(false); 
         break;
      }
   }

   // modify ends

   // rest of the codes...

}
```

Comment: if(!dayNums.get(i).isChecked) is working i can find only isempty....ischecked i cant find